# How to center align a view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to lay a variable number of views (may just be one) next to each other like in LinearLayout. But I want the whole arrangement to be center aligned. The views should be next to each other. But the whole arrangement should be equidistant from the left and right edge of the screen or the containing parent. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will have to wrap your views inside a `LinearLayout` and your linear layout inside something else:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
       <View/>
       <View/>
       etc...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure all your views use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. If you are working with `RelativeLayout`, it will be:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
       <View/>
       <View/>
       <View/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 11):

Did you try

```
      android:gravity="center"
```

?

Answer (score 2):

This will do it for you

android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Also you want to consider the weight property to make sure that this layout element takes priority over others.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

To group everything together you can use a Frame Layout or Relative Layout.